# spawning urdf in gazebo_ros

Tags: ros, urdf, gazebo-ros, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to spawn a simple urdf box in gazebo? I want to spawn an entire robot but the gazebo tutorials on this have a bit complicated launch files and use complicatted .xacro robots. I'm on a beginner level, my simple robot is just .urdf not even using .xacro.

A box like this!

```
 <robot name="origins">
<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size ="8.8 0.4 2"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <box size ="8.8 0.4 2"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
        <inertial>
                <inertia ixx="0.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0"/>
        <mass value="0.1"/>
        </inertial>
</link>


</robot>
```

I'm trying to use the command rosrun gazebo_ros spwan_model but it just says:

Loading model xml from file

Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model.

Nothing more happens...

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203838/spawning-urdf-in-gazebo_ros/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you start gazebo before running the command?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-02-26**:
I started gazebo & roscore.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-02-26**:
What is the output of rosservice list?